# Wrong operations in for loop, Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Ok, so I import some data and I make an operation in order to compute a quantity with physical meaning.
Here all entries are positive: y1>0, P>0 and x1>0 and when computing g1 somehow I end having an array g1 with negative entries... Also Psat1>0

```
g1    = np.zeros(len(P))
g2    = g1
GEsRT = g1

for k in range(1,end-1):
#Tener cuidado con índices
g1[k] = y1[k]*P[k]/Psat1/x1[k]
y2 = 1 - y1[k]
x2 = 1 - x1[k]
g2[k] = y2*P[k]/(Psat2*x2)
```

UPDATE: I discovered that if I comment other operations, the resulting array g1 has different values, which makes no sense to me.

:(

Comment: Can you please provide us with some variables, for testing?

Comment: Can you print out y1,P,Psat and x1?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.

Comment: Sorry, it needs the data in order to perform the operations, but is solved!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I tried to do something very common in Matlab, but I got the error:

```
g1    = np.zeros(len(P))
g2    = np.zeros(len(P))
GEsRT = np.zeros(len(P))

for k in range(1,end-1):
#Tener cuidado con índices
g1[k] = y1[k]*P[k]/Psat1/x1[k]
y2 = 1 - y1[k]
x2 = 1 - x1[k]
g2[k] = y2*P[k]/(Psat2*x2)
```

The way it handles variables is not the same as in Matlab.